# RSA private key calculate [MADLIB]

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa, private-key

How can I calculate the private key(d)?
The problem is that d(private key) has to be an int number but I keep getting d=0.0000152585.. Help please?

```
p=92092076805892533739724722602668675840671093008520241548191914215399824020372076186460768206814914423802230398410980218741906960527104568970225804374404612617736579286959865287226538692911376507934256844456333236362669879347073756238894784951597211105734179388300051579994253565459304743059533646753003894559

q=97846775312392801037224396977012615848433199640105786119757047098757998273009741128821931277074555731813289423891389911801250326299324018557072727051765547115514791337578758859803890173153277252326496062476389498019821358465433398338364421624871010292162533041884897182597065662521825095949253625730631876637

e=65537

n=9010912747277787249738727439840427055736519196538871349093408340706668231808840540195374015916168031416186859836416053338250477003776576736854137538279810042409758765948034443613881324504120707334213544491046703922409406729564516371394804946909037646047891880347940067132730874804943893719672960932378043325067514786209219718314429979032869544980643978919561908707109629612202311323626173343456843249212057093980583352634168733656443959925428846968193413110401346035535595817965624054783296380268863401241570313602685481219583686719199499297832165308522137209299081956650614940546284136240753995440003473611843518083

ϕ(n)=9010912747277787249738727439840427055736519196538871349093408340706668231808840540195374015916168031416186859836416053338250477003776576736854137538279810042409758765948034443613881324504120707334213544491046703922409406729564516371394804946909037646047891880347940067132730874804943893719672960932378043324975422709403327184574705256430200869139972885911041667158917715396802487303254097156996075042397142670178352954223188514914536999398324277997967608735996733417799016531005758767556757687357486893307313469146352244856913807372125743058937380356924926103564902568350563360552030570781449252380469826858839623524
```

So with the formula:

d=e<sup>-1</sup> mod ϕ(n)

I keep getting 0.0000152585. Any ideas?

Comment: [Modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)

Comment: So I guess "e" is the integer? and ϕ(n) is the modulo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the **Modular Multiplicative Inverse**, not the inverse.
Here is an example in python using the `cryptography` module.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric.rsa import _modinv

p=92092076805892533739724722602668675840671093008520241548191914215399824020372076186460768206814914423802230398410980218741906960527104568970225804374404612617736579286959865287226538692911376507934256844456333236362669879347073756238894784951597211105734179388300051579994253565459304743059533646753003894559
q=97846775312392801037224396977012615848433199640105786119757047098757998273009741128821931277074555731813289423891389911801250326299324018557072727051765547115514791337578758859803890173153277252326496062476389498019821358465433398338364421624871010292162533041884897182597065662521825095949253625730631876637
e=65537

phi = (p-1) * (q-1)
d = _modinv(e, phi)

print(d)              #  1405046269503207469140791548403639533127416416214210694972085079171787580463776820425965898174272870486015739516125786182821637006600742140682552321645503743280670839819078749092730110549881891271317396450158021688253989767145578723458252769465545504142139663476747479225923933192421405464414574786272963741656223941750084051228611576708609346787101088759062724389874160693008783334605903142528824559223515203978707969795087506678894006628296743079886244349469131831225757926844843554897638786146036869572653204735650843186722732736888918789379054050122205253165705085538743651258400390580971043144644984654914856729
print((e * d) % phi)  #  1
```

You can find the implementation of [_modinv()](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography/blob/master/src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py) here.

Answer (score 1):

By [fips.186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/fips/nist.fips.186-4.pdf#page=62) standard, you have to use λ not φ in RSA;

```
λ(n)=lcm(p−1,q−1)
```

to calculate `d= e-1 mod λ(n)` you must use [extendedGCD](https://www.wikizero.com/en/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) algorithm.

find x and y that satisfify [Bezout Identity](https://www.wikizero.com/en/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

```
e x + λ(n) y = gcd(e,λ(n))
e x -1 = (-y)λ(n)
```

take mod λ(n)

```
e x ≡ 1 mod λ(n)
```

Comment: I've found this python3 script (https://gist.github.com/ofaurax/6103869014c246f962ab30a513fb5b49) for modular multiplicative inverse and just replaced p,q and e in the script and worked for me. But thanks for your answer, I think is good your way of solving. :)

Comment: RSA works with either phi (Euler) or lambda (Carmichael), and the original CACM paper used Euler (although PKCS1 published by RSALabs used Carmichael); there are numerous Qs on crypto.SX about this. NIST likes to prohibit any variability not necessary for security to reduce opportunities for interoperability problems, hence Carmichael. PS: in your previous comment you want lcm() * gcd() not lcm() * gcd(lcm()) which makes no sense.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks for noticing the mistake, and information.

Comment: Use the standard. That is textbook RSA that uses φ. Use this relation to find the `λ(n)`, `lcm(p−1,q−1)* gcd(p−1,q−1) = (p−1)*(q−1)`. *previous has paste copy error*. Thanks to Dave